# Using .Include() in a database query creates an infinite loop of data

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**The problem**: I'm using a LINQ to query against an Entity Framework context to a relational database. Following along with [EFCore Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships), I made a database with a few relationships, but when I sent the data to the server using ASP.NET, I got null values for these relationships.

With a little more digging, I found that I needed to use `_context.Post.Include("Blog")` to send the data since it uses lazy loading. However, by doing this, it created an "infinite loop" in the JsonResult.

The data that ends up getting returned appears to be cut in half and I get JSON parse errors when loading it because it's missing the second half of the JSON data.

Example return value

```
{"id": 0, "blogId": 1, "blog": {"postId":0
```

That's all it returns, as anything after that postId would be a reference back to the original post, which in turn has a reference to the blog. Is there any way that I can use LINQ to exclude the post object in the return, similar to how the blog was included in the first place?

Comment: You need to provide more details about your DB's tables and relations between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed! I took the model that came from the database with the relationship included, then used a foreach to null out the reverse reference.

```
var blog = await _context.Blog
    .Include(x => x.Posts)
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);

foreach (Post post in blog.Posts)
{
    post.Blog = null;
}
return Ok(blog);
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't scale well when dealing with a large number of complex classes.  I took a crack at using reflection for this issue before and it got messy.  Not to mention that the additional processing takes away from performance.

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON serialization problem.
Search how to solve "circulare references" problem in your JSON stream serializer documentation.
Different stream serializers provide different solutions:

1. configure max depth
2. history based on references cache
3. configure specific types serializers to do not use "navigation properties"

Other solution - do not use stream serializers - configure serializer function at place.

And another one - use DTO classes (where there are no circular references).

You can also try to detach your entities and set null to every navigation property you want to ignore but this is ugly and can't be recommended.

Comment: I'm not doing any of the serialization myself, it's all being done by ASP when it returns it as an ActionResult. It just gives up and then returns until the point before it gave up and doesn't bother to fix the markup.

Comment: I know. But you should. Choose one: configure JSON serializer globally to handle circular references, serialize data by yourself or convert entities to DTO.

Comment: It's using the scaffolded API controller, which I can imagine is the "correct" way to do things.

Comment: 1) scaffolder is just a very basic tool. many things are absent that should be in real controller (logging, telemetry, sql server message parsing, rowversion support, many to many support etc ). 2)  "circular references" is a fundamental serialization problem. no one programmer can't avoid it.

Comment: I just don't get why the circular reference is there at all. The docs say that if I want to include a level, I need to include it because it won't be automatically sent, yet it just seems to magically send it.

Comment: Need to load all navigations consistently is obvious when we track entities and not obvious when we do not need tracking. But EF is about tracking otherwise we could use e.g. linq for sql.